# Помогите с выбором технологий для написания чата

Tags: php, node.js, chat

Недавно появилась задача написать чат на `nodejs`.
Чат - похож на чат `Facebook`'a.
Остановился на технологии `nodejs` и `rethinkDb`. Так же пришёл к выводу что надо использовать `socket`.
Но проблема в том что в `nodejs` и `rethinkDb` не сильно разбираюсь. Разбираюсь в `php` и обычном `js`.
Подскажите, стоит ли заморачиваться с нодой и ресинком для чата? 
Может подскажите, которые использовать технологии лучше?
И если писать чат на `php` стоит ли использовать сокеты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сокеты нужны будут, если нужно моментальное взаимодействие клиентов с сервером. Если моментальное взаимодействие не важно, можно обойтись простым ajax'ом.

**PHP**:

На PHP есть библиотека [Ratched](http://socketo.me/), которая позволяет поднимать сокеты(сам ею пользовался для написании чата).

**NodeJS**:

С нодой попроще писать чат. У node.js есть модуль, называется [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), которая, по личному опыту, работает чуть стабильнее, чем Ratched у PHP.

В принципе, я писал чаты по обеим вышеперечисленным способам и вывод - на NodeJS писать, лично для меня, - удобнее и быстрее, правда там могут возникнуть проблемы с асинхронностью(для программиста на PHP это подводные камни).

*P.S. По поводу ajax, думаю, объяснять не стоит.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а вы какую бд использовали?

Comment: По желанию заказчика, использовал MySQL, но использовать его вам не советую. Смотрите в сторону нереляционных баз данных. Они, в отличии от MySQL, работают быстрее и для чата самое то.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с mix. Думаю стоит использовать nodejs по некоторым причинам:

1 если вы решили использовать сокеты, то на `php` есть проблема [утечки памяти](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71613);
2 Один язык программирования на проекте лучше чем несколько языков;
3 Низкий порог вхождения. Если вы знаете js, то вам не надо учить новый язык программирования

С rethinkDB тоже хороший выбор как для чата. 
Бесплатно его можно использовать 30 дне на https://app.compose.io

Вот вот небольшие примеры [nodejs + rethinkDb](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-example-nodejs)